# Convert a string using icu4c?

Tags: icu

How can I convert a string from one encoding to another using icu4c? I've searched for hours and have not found anything except from looking at the source of uconv (a utility bundled with icu4c), it calls `ucnv_open` (which takes encodings as parameters) at some point. I'd assume you can use the result of `ucnv_open` to convert a string somehow...

Answer (score 0):

uconv would help you, but also see:

- http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion
- http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html
- http://source.icu-project.org/repos/icu/icu/trunk/source/samples/ucnv/convsamp.cpp  ( a simpler sample also within your ICU source tree )